# TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable, old solution didn't worked

Tags: python, django

I am learning django and I'm getting this error and even when I go to admin the CSS is also not loading. the things I have added on models.py are also not showing on admin. Please Some one help me to get out of this problem. I tried searching google and youtube.

**Error**

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/subas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/subas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/subas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/Users/subas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 224, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "/Users/subas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 248, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "/Users/subas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 367, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "/Users/subas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'PosixPath' is not iterable`
```

**Model.py**

`````
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:category-list', args=[self.slug])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Product_creator')
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Non-branded')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    in_Stock = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_pliral = 'Products'
    ordering = ('-Created', )

def __str__(self):
    return self.title ````
`````

Comment: Can you please share your `DATABASE` settings?

Comment: I have posted settings.py's code below please check that out.